# Fonts 2x the Size on iPhone Compared to Browser Device Simulator?

Tags: css, reactjs, ios-simulator, google-chrome-devtools, safari-web-inspector

I have the following in my html header:

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

...and the web app I'm developing looks fine in the device simulators in Chrome, Safari, Firefox, etc. But when I load it on an actual iPhone, or in the Xcode iPhone simulator, all the fonts seem to be about twice the size.

How can I correct this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code in your CSS

-webkit-text-size-adjust: none | auto | ;

So, twice as big would be: -webkit-text-size-adjust: 200%;

Comment: At this time there are no .css files. My app uses React, and all styling is currently inline. "React favors an inline approach for styling content that doesn't use CSS." https://www.kirupa.com/react/styling_in_react.htm

Comment: so, use inline css like, <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: none | auto |<percentage> ;"/>

Comment: I'm concerned about using text-size-adjust. This site says it is "experimental". https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-size-adjust.